# Calling reboot --force via ssh: Will the ssh session disconnecting happens before rebooting?

Tags: ssh, reboot

I need run `reboot --force` via ssh in a script automatically, (don't worry about the --force will cause data lost, I have issued `sync` command before).

I have done it successfully so far by following method:

```
orig_args=(bash -c "nohup reboot --force >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &")

args=(); for v in "${orig_args[@]}"; do args+=("$(printf %q "$v")"); done

ssh host "${args[@]}"
```

which means

```
bash -c "nohup reboot --force >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &"
```

i.e., run the `reboot --force` in foreground even if ssh connection is closed.

I hope that the ssh session disconnecting happens before rebooting, but not sure,

i.e., is following case possible?

if the os starts the reboot background job too fast,
then it may cause ssh connection disconnected,
therefore the ssh command itself fails.

I hope the answer is false, is there anything that support my hope?

If the answer is "uncertain", then I can not take the risk, I am going to use another **cumbersome** method to ensure it, such as

```
orig_args=(bash -c "nohup bash -c 'sleep 1; reboot --force' >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &")

args=(); for v in "${orig_args[@]}"; do args+=("$(printf %q "$v")"); done

ssh host "${args[@]}"

sleep 2
```

which means after ssh command exits, 1 second later, run `reboot --force` on the server. Then on client side, wait for 2 seconds.

by this way, I can ensure

- the ssh command will always succeed.
- after the whole script exit, the server should have been at least power-ed off.